# What is a stationary distribution?

Tags: time-series, distributions, stationarity, marginal-distribution

Today I was reading about AR(1) processes and I there was something I didn't understand:

For the casual solution $X(t-1)$ and $\epsilon(t)$ are independent, and when $\epsilon(t)$-s are standard normal random variables, the stationary solution has normal marginals: $X(t)\sim N(0, \sigma^2_X)$, where one has that $\sigma^2_X=\frac{\sigma ^2_\epsilon}{1-\alpha^2}$

Is the stationary distribution simply the distribution of $X(t)$, and what does "normal marginals" mean?

Comment: Answers to the marginal distribution question can be found from links on a search of ["marginal distribution definition"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22marginal+distribution%22+definition).  Information about stationary time series is available through links at [stationary time series definition](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22stationary%22+time-series+definition).